# How to build single nuget package for multiple projects in a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nuget, nuget-package, octopus-deploy

I have a web application solution with more than one projects within it. I am using Octopack to prepare the build and publish it on to my web server.

My web application deployment structure looks like this

-My Web App (Root folder)
  - WS1 (Virtual directory)
  - WS2 (Virtual directory)
  - PT1 
  - PT2

Here, WS1 and WS2 are the virtual directories. PT1 and PT2 are the physical directories representing different projects.

On building my solution which has four different projects corresponding to the deployment structure stated above. Each project has the reference for OCTOPACK, on building the solution with MSBUILD I notice that 4 different nuget packages are built.

Is there any way to build into a single package having the above stated deployment structure for deploying in OCTOPUS DEPLOY. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would be the advantage to having one instead of four?  Wouldn't you want Octopus to deploy each project to the web server separately?

Comment: @BruceVanHorn Advantage would be that, I can manage to see one package for each release version on the Octopus deploy and more over I do have a single web server in which all my services are configured under one Root application as virtual directories.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can because Octopus Deploy doesn't seem to support granularity above the project level.  If you could deploy a solution in total, what you're asking could work, but the process steps available in Octopus are pretty much leveled out at one project each.  I see the allure of one deployment for what is to your way of thinking a single product release with four things in it, but the settings for Octopus obviates a 1:1 ration of sites / services per deploy.

If you ditch Octopus Deploy, you could probably get team city or a build script to make one nuget package, and then you could use powershell, or maybe something like [final builder](https://www.finalbuilder.com/) to deploy.  Come to think of it, Final Builder would probably do the whole thing including generating the single package.

But then you lose the awesomeness of the Octopus dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

use this parameter while creating the package with octopack /p:OctoPackProjectName=your package filename